# Why do cards from Alpha have to be in opaque sleeves?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

In [this answer](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/a/28809/15277) the [tournament rules](http://wpn.wizards.com/sites/wpn/files/attachements/mtg_mtr_22jan16_en.pdf) are quoted:

> **3.3 Authorized Cards**
>
> [...]
>
> Players may use cards from the Alpha printing **only if the deck is in opaque sleeves**.

**Why is this?** As far as I remember there was an idea of having different card backs for each edition/expansion, but it was decided later to have the only one card back, which makes all cards compatible.

**What makes cards from Alpha different so that they could be recognized without an opaque sleeve?**

Comment: Related: http://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/5120/how-can-i-tell-the-difference-between-early-magic-the-gathering-card-editions (talks about differences between all early sets without set symbols; the answer specifically for alpha is buried in there)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Since the corners of alpha cards are distinctly different from the other editions of magic cards, it would be equivalent to playing with a marked deck, since presumably all your cards won't be alpha.