# Are white bordered cards allowed in DCI sanctioned tournaments?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

Everywhere I look has specific ban lists for Magic. I have heard that "all white border cards are banned in DCI sanctioned tournaments" But my 'Stream of Life' is white bordered and not listed on the modern banned list.

Are all white bordered cards banned in DCI events?

Comment: Although the question is different, the correct answer is given here: https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/28808/can-i-draw-something-on-my-card-and-play-tournaments-with-it

Comment: Note that specific cards are banned based on the card name; not which set they came from. So the fact that your specific Stream of Life is white bordered wouldn't affect if Stream of Life is on the banned list. If Stream of life were banned, all versions of it would be banned no matter what color boarder it has.

Comment: I note that in your title you ask "Are white bordered cards _allowed_...?" but in the body you ask "Are white bordered cards _banned_...?" which may lead to confusion. I suggest editing the title to match the body.

Comment: White bordered cards are both legal and ugly :)

Comment: What you likely heard was that "all _silver_ border cards are banned in DCI sanctioned tournaments" - such cards are from the _Un_-sets (and also the Wizards holiday cards) and are all illegal for sanctioned play.

Comment: (Gold-bordered cards are also banned in DCI sanctioned tournaments; those are 'specialty' reprints of cards that might be otherwise tournament-legal. For instance, a gold-bordered Stream of Life was printed in the original Collector's Set; that card is illegal for tournament play even in formats where Stream of Life is legal.)

Comment: I do want to add to this that there may never be a visual difference between the cards in your deck when looking at them face down! I know of someone who was disqualified for using white bordered lands because you can tell them apart from black bordered by looking at the edges. Also in a major tournament a player was banned once for using 4 foils in his deck. With a slightly more curved card as result.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Yes, white bordered cards are legal.

From the [Magic: The Gathering Tournament Rules](http://wpn.wizards.com/en/resources/rules-documents/244) ([English version](http://wpn.wizards.com/sites/wpn/files/attachements/mtg_mtr_28apr17_en.updated.pdf)):

> Players may use any Authorized Game Cards from Magic: The Gathering
>   expansions, core sets, special sets, supplements, and promotional
>   printings. Authorized Game Cards are cards that, unaltered, meet the
>   following conditions:

**The card is genuine and published by Wizards of the Coast**

> It is important to remember that fake Magic cards exist. Usually,
>   these cards can be identified as fake under scrutiny. If these cards
>   are found to be in use in a tournament, they should not continue to be
>   used. Also, the player using the card may not realize that they are
>   using fake cards, so aside from alerting them that they are using fake
>   cards and informing them that they must replace them, we, as judges,
>   should not take further action unless we believe they knew and were
>   using such cards intentionally.
>
> Also, Tournament Officials do not have the legal authority to
>   confiscate fake cards and should not attempt to do so. Stopping their
>   use in the event is sufficient.

**The card has a standard Magic back or is a double-faced card, or is a card that is part of a meld pair.**

> Artist proofs are published by Wizards of the Coast, but do not have a
>   standard Magic back. They are, therefore, not usable in tournament
>   play.

**The card does not have squared corners.**

> Collectors’ Edition cards have black borders on the face, but square
>   corners and a gold border on the back. These are not legal for
>   tournament use. Also, uncut sheets of cards are sometimes cut for use.
>   It is important that these cards have the same corners as all other
>   cards.

**The card has non-silver borders.**

> Cards from Unglued and Unhinged have silver borders with a standard
>   Magic back. These are not legal for play. Gold bordered cards also
>   exist, though they do not have a standard Magic back.

**The card is not a token card.**

> Tokens are used to represent objects that don’t exist as normal Magic
>   cards. While some official tokens exist, it is not required that they
>   be used during tournament play.

**The card is not damaged or modified in a way that might make it marked.**

> Significantly creased cards can be distinguished from other cards in a
>   deck, even sleeved. Also, altered cards may be thicker than the other
>   cards in the deck, depending on the method used to alter the card. If
>   any cards can be distinguished from the other cards in the deck
>   without viewing its front face, then those cards are marked and not
>   legal for tournament play.

**The card is otherwise legal for the tournament as defined by the format.**

> The cards being played in the deck must be printed in a set that is
>   legal in the format, even if the printing being used is from an
>   otherwise illegal set. For example, it is okay to use the Stronghold
>   printing of Mana Leak in Modern even though Stronghold is not a legal
>   set for use in Modern.

Answer (score 7):

White bordered card are legal.The only border color that is illegal for  sanctioned play is silver, all other border colors aren't inherently illegal (gold bordered cards are also not legal, but that is because they have a non-standard back not because of the border color).

Also cards are banned based on the card's name, and not any other features of the card. So for example [Shock](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bShock%5d) is currently legal in Standard because it was printed in Aether Revolt, but I can play any version of it I want to like the [7th Edition](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=13074) version which has a white border (and the old card frame).

From the [Magic Tournament Rules](http://wpn.wizards.com/sites/wpn/files/attachements/mtg_mtr_28apr17_en.updated.pdf):

> **3.3 Authorized Cards**
>   Players may use any Authorized Game Cards from Magic: The Gathering expansions, core sets, special sets, supplements, and promotional printings. Authorized Game Cards are cards that, unaltered, meet the following conditions:
>
> - The card is genuine and published by Wizards of the Coast
> - The card has a standard Magic back, is a double-faced card, or is a card that is part of a meld pair.
> - The card does not have squared corners.
> - The card has non-silver borders.
> - The card is not a token card.
> - The card is not damaged or modified in a way that might make it marked.
> - The card is otherwise legal for the tournament as defined by the format.

Answer (score 3):

White-bordered cards are completely legal. The criteria for determining whether a card is legal in tournament play are laid out in the [Magic Tournament Rules](http://wpn.wizards.com/sites/wpn/files/attachements/mtg_mtr_28apr17_en.updated.pdf) section 3.3:

> Players may use any Authorized Game Cards from Magic: The Gathering expansions, core sets, special sets, supplements, and promotional printings. Authorized Game Cards are cards that, unaltered, meet the following conditions:
>
> - The card is genuine and published by Wizards of the Coast
> - The card has a standard Magic back, is a double-faced card, or is a card that is part of a meld pair.
> - The card does not have squared corners.
> - **The card has non-silver borders.**
> - The card is not a token card.
> - The card is not damaged or modified in a way that might make it marked.
> - The card is otherwise legal for the tournament as defined by the format.